# dotnet publish changes assembly version of assemblies under the same solution

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-6.0

I have 3 projects.

```
MicroService1
MicroService1.Core
MicroService1.Web
```

MicroService.Web references both MicroService 1 and MicroService1.Core.

In MicroService1.Web I have the following under the project file

[image]

When I run `dotnet.exe publish ./MicroService1.Web/MicroService1.Web.csproj --framework net6.0 --configuration Release --runtime win-x64 --self-contained true` it creates three assemblies MicroService1.dll, MicroService1.Core.dll and MicroService1.Web.dll
Inspecting version of all of them (using right click => details) returns the following

```
MicroService1.dll - 1.0.0.0
MicroService1.Core.dll - 1.0.0.0
MicroService1.Web.dll - 2.1.1.1
```

Which is correct since we only set version for MicroService1.Web

using exactly the same script in azure devops pipeline produces the following:

```
MicroService1.dll - 2.1.1.1
MicroService1.Core.dll - 2.1.1.1
MicroService1.Web.dll - 2.1.1.1
```

Why does this happen? How can I stop this?

Comment: In Azure Pipeline log, can you check the command executed by the agent?

Comment: I think the problem is a step that I use to set a task variable named version and for some reason it was using that variable ````Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=version]$version"```` This step cause the issue so I renamed to ````Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=appVersion]$version"```` and it resolved the issue. Strange things..